# What is tortilla flour?

Tags: flour

I've accidentally ordered tortilla flour for my kitchen instead of flour tortillas.

The meal was saved, but I don't know anything about this flour specifically. What type of flour is it closest to? What can it or can it not be used for? Is it a different grind?

Comment: Is it labeled as "masa harina?"

Comment: A picture of the package would probably help us figure out really basic questions, like did you get corn or wheat flour.

Answer (score 2):

Tortilla is basically Mexican bread to make Quesadilla, Enchiladas or tacos. It is a fine ground flour containing either wheat or corn for wheat tortilla and corn tortilla.